# How to connect to particular port by aws elb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have two ec2 instances and deployed java apps to '/var/www/html'. 
They are running in port 9010 and I can access them by 'http://xxxx:9010'.

Next,I created elb and added the two instances to it.However,I can't access the java app by elb public dns 'http:elbxxxxx:9010'. It returned 404.

I put index.html to '/var/www/html/' , I can see index.html by elb public dns.

I'm looking for some configurations for ports in elb console but I can't.

How can I access them?

Comment: follow the link and configure listerners: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-add-or-delete-listeners.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure a [listener](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html) on the Elastic Load Balancer. Your listener can be configured to listen on any port (such as 80) and send the requests to your instances on port 9010. Here's how to [configure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-add-or-delete-listeners.html) listeners.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem. I created a application load balancer , and I was'nt able to find the configration for days. So, I destroyed the load balancer and have created a classic load balancer.I could configure the lister soon.